# Wrong background image for navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios8, uinavigationbar, uibarmetrics

I ran into this issue in iOS 8 where the wrong background image for the navigation bar is displayed in any of these situations:

- the view controller-based status bar appearance is set to `YES` (default) and the navigation controller is presented modally.
- the view controller-based status bar appearance is set to `NO` and the status bar is initially hidden. In this case, the navigation controller does not need to be presented modally to display the wrong image.

To isolate the problem where the view controller-based status bar appearance is set to YES (default) and the navigation controller is presented modally I created a test project from scratch following these steps:

1. Create a new project with the "Master-Detail Application" template.
2. Open `Main.storyboard` and add a Navigation Controller to it. Remove its root view controller and connect the Master View Controller with a **modal segue**. Then connect the Detail View Controller as its root view controller. You should end up with something like this:

[image]

3. Customise the navigation bar background via the appearance proxy. Use two different images for portrait (`UIBarMetricsDefault`) and landscape (`UIBarMetricsCompact`). I used a category on `UIImage` to create the images from solid colors.

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
       // Override point for customization after application launch.
       [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor redColor]] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
       [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsCompact];

       return YES;
   }
   ```
4. Run the app. The Master view controller displays the right navigation bar background images for portrait and landscape orientations:

[image]

[image]

5. Now present the Detail view controller modally. To do so, tap on the "Add" button and then select the newly created row. The Detail view controller displays the **right** navigation bar background image.
6. Rotate the interface. The Detail view controller will **not** change the navigation bar background image (**wrong**):

[image]

7. Rotate the interface back to its original orientation. The Detail view controller will change the navigation bar background image (**wrong**):

[image]

Has anyone else struggled with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,I have been struggling with this, after I add `"View controller-based status bar appearance"` in target's plist file, it is working again on iOS 8, remember to set it to `NO`.

In MasterViewController, add this to avoid wrong background image when detailViewController is dismissed. It basically set the same appearance again.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor redColor]] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsCompact];
}
```

Comment: +1. This *almost* solves the problem (if you are willing to give up on the view controller-based status bar appearance). Now when the Detail view controller is rotated, the **right** navigation bar background image is displayed. However, when the Detail view controller is dismissed (after at least one rotation), the Master view controller displays the **wrong** navigation bar background image (until the interface is rotated again). Does the same happen to you?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge with me. This fixes the issue if the status bar is **not** initially hidden. I'm accepting your answer although it's more a hacky workaround for a nasty bug than a clean solution.

Comment: Yes,there are problems when status bar is initially hidden,more work need to be done to fix all issues.